# cannot set two <p> value on ajax success

Tags: jquery, ajax

i recently tried to display value form database into multiple `<p>` tag.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label for="cust_name" class="col-md-3">Nama Debitur: </label>
        <p class="col-md-3"><span id="cust_name" >...</span></p>
        <label for="app_id" class="col-md-3">Application Id: </label>
        <p class="col-md-3"><span id="app_id" >...</span></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label for="agrmnt_no" class="col-md-3">Agreement No: </label>
        <p class="col-md-3" id="agrmnt_no"></p>
        <label for="contract_stat" class="col-md-3">Contract status: </label>
        <p class="col-md-3" id="contract_stat"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my ajax jquery.

```
    function load_detil_debitur(){
  var app_id = $('#app_id').val();

  $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url();?>c_detail_sample/get_detil_debitur",
      type: 'POST',
      datatype: 'json',
      data: {'app_id': app_id},
          success: function(data) {
        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        $('#cust_name').html(json.debitur[0].app_no);
        $('#app_id').html('test'); //didn't affect anything

        $('#timeline').hide();
        $('#content-item').show();
          },error: function(data) {
              alertify.error("Terjadi kesalahan pengambilan data!");
          }
    });
}
```

i tried write other value to console and it had no problem with it, but when i tried to set the value on second element, then nothing happened.

Comment: Let me know, which two <p> tag values you want to set on ajax success so I can help you.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your browser's console?

Comment: Double check that you have no other elements on the page withe the ID `app_id` . Is `$('#cust_name').html(json.debitur[0].app_no);` populating as expected?